# w2ui grid infinite scroll without using a the url feature

Tags: javascript, w2ui

Basically, I want to use the infinite scroll mechanism in the w2ui grid without having to use the url feature. We have to put credentials into our calls to the back end in the headers so using the url feature is not an option. Any ideas if that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in my case I can tap into the `request` event and modify the request by adding request headers or anything else needed. See the documentation here:

[w2ui onRequest](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.onRequest)